# Django Serializer with Websockets not working due to request and HyperLinkedModelSerializer

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-channels, channel

I am trying to use a websockets to send a queryset to my frontend using a model serializer.

When I test this out I receive the following message:

`"HyperlinkedIdentityField" requires the request in the serializer context. Add context={'request': request} when instantiating the serializer.`

This is my frontend test code:

```
function websocket_test(){

  ws.send(JSON.stringify({
    action: "list",
    request_id: new Date().getTime()
  }))
}
```

This is my serializer:

```
class InstructorSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=Instructor
        fields='__all__'
```

This is my consumer:

```
class Instructors_Consumer(
        ListModelMixin,
        RetrieveModelMixin,
        PatchModelMixin,
        UpdateModelMixin,
        CreateModelMixin,
        DeleteModelMixin,
        GenericAsyncAPIConsumer):
    queryset=Instructor.objects.all()
    serializer_class=InstructorSerializer
```

I don't quite understand what is going wrong. The error raised mentions adding a context keyword when I instantiate the serializer; however I have no clue on why it would need the request or where to instantiate.

Any help would be greatly appreciated as I'm completely lost on how to fix this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: So it needs a request so it will: "...ensure that the hyperlinks can include an appropriate hostname, so that the resulting representation uses fully qualified URLs..." ..I'm no sure on a solution, but you might have to remove it from `serializer_class=` and just manually call the serializer in a `connect` or `receive` function / when you have a Request Obj

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is to not user HyperlinkedModelSerializer and instead to use the ModelSerializer so that it does not use the request for the url routing in the serializer.

Cheers